Flutter run error - Could not find io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0
Im relatively new to flutter and im trying to run the app with flutter run with a running emulator in android studio.
i've been constantly getting this error and i'm unable to get rid of it:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.flutter:x86_64_debug:1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find io.flutter:x86_debug:1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233/x86_debug-1.0.0-36335019a8eab588c3c2ea783c618d90505be233.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

flutter doctor output:
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 15.0 24A335 darwin-x64, locale en-EG)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    ✗ Flutter requires Xcode 14 or higher.
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.93.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

any help would be appreciated!
PS. I'm on MacOS and using the correct Dart SDK shipped with Flutter

Can you share the output of running flutter doctor?

@tomerpacific i edited the question above to include flutter doctor

This question is similar to: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception (Flutter). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@tomerpacific i followed it and it has not solved my problem

Try this:
flutter channel stable && flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter run

